# Verify offline an Azure AD generated JWT

Tags: security, jwt, azure-active-directory

I'm getting an error when verifying an Azure AD generated token. This is the current setup:

- I have a token which can be pasted on https://jwt.io, and I can see in the right panel the correct claims. I assume the token is correctly formatted. I can also see in the headers that `kid = piVlloQDSMKxh1m2ygqGSVdgFpA` and `alg: RS256`. I set correctly the algo type to RS256 for verification.
- I went to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys to find the public key, and found the same `kid = piVlloQDSMKxh1m2ygqGSVdgFpA`. So I copied the corresponds public key (the string in the `x5c` field) and wrapped it into the correct strings to make it *PKCS#8*. compatible:

  -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
  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
  -----END CERTIFICATE-----

In case it's not visible above, there is a `\n` after `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and before `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`

- That public key got copied in the public key part of it, and in my code it's the public RSA key.
- I also tried formatting using *PKCS#1*, I didn't get more success

It keeps being invalid. Not even expired, clearly invalid, both on jwt.io and in my code.

Assuming the token is correct, is my methodology correct? I found different tutorials preparing the .pem differently. If my token is incorrect, how can I check that aside of getting claims from it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to generate the public key from `modulus` and `exponent`.

You can get them from `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId_or_commom}/discovery/v2.0/keys`

[image]

Here is a java sample for your reference:

```
    public static PublicKey getPublicKey(String encodedModulus, String encodedExponent) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        byte[] modulus = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(encodedModulus);
        byte[] exponent = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(encodedExponent);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : modulus) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        }
        String sm = sb.toString();

        sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : exponent) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        }
        String se = sb.toString();

        BigInteger bm = new BigInteger(sm,16);
        BigInteger be = new BigInteger(se,16);

        KeyFactory rsa = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey publicKey = rsa.generatePublic(new RSAPublicKeySpec(bm, be));

        return publicKey;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String modulus = "0XhhwpmEpN-jDBapnzhFbtvEU2BpLLcaLzlXm4mlT2MwKZlXRUUam2vI0URDUYRKaa4O62BCWSSGOv2LGQ6tMD5oU-Dqkuf44bo1hLufIqAALUymssfRurTrLd0fqVA9ZCF3fA8_7xQi5r370m4h-G71ez8eE3lxiVPlwSeJXRpa5QzGA8ApwbXGiV-6liGU4eMXBU39A5rFy6TdioaC4P6xns-IdwlLMWdOR28P4O0yhbVTqcN_kW4N4AQonslB_tGOJGhWJjFkcqsQ8cbiJn6Q6FXoNADXohJO3sAtdUHyBNMXc68i25uTYTe_qyCKuC290TkyR3gxMlw7rtuB1Q";
        String exponent = "AQAB";
        byte[] bytes = getPublicKey(modulus, exponent).getEncoded();
        String encodedString = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes));

        System.out.println("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----");
        System.out.println(encodedString);
        System.out.println("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----");

        System.out.println();
    }
```

You will get some outputs as following:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA0XhhwpmEpN+jDBapnzhFbtvEU2BpLLcaLzlXm4mlT2MwKZlXRUUam2vI0URDUYRKaa4O62BCWSSGOv2LGQ6tMD5oU+Dqkuf44bo1hLufIqAALUymssfRurTrLd0fqVA9ZCF3fA8/7xQi5r370m4h+G71ez8eE3lxiVPlwSeJXRpa5QzGA8ApwbXGiV+6liGU4eMXBU39A5rFy6TdioaC4P6xns+IdwlLMWdOR28P4O0yhbVTqcN/kW4N4AQonslB/tGOJGhWJjFkcqsQ8cbiJn6Q6FXoNADXohJO3sAtdUHyBNMXc68i25uTYTe/qyCKuC290TkyR3gxMlw7rtuB1QIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

And then you can use it in jwt.io:
[image]

Comment: Super helpful, getting there! I coded that on my side, I have the same public key as you, which is encouraging. Also it's the same than what appears by default in the textbox for the public key on https://jwt.io (how do they get that?). Nevertheless it's not marked as Verified yet. I don't understand where to look next, could it be a truncated token? Would the token debugger still find the correct public key automatically in that case?

Comment: Could you please share a token you got? An expired one would be OK.

Comment: By the way, may I know if you get the token for Microsoft Graph API?

Comment: If you get the token for Graph API, the token contains a nonce and requires special processing during validation. In other words, only Graph can validate it. For more about this, you may refer to the Github issue page: [#812](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/812#issuecomment-456700813) , [#609](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/609)

Comment: @nlassaux Have some new findings, check comments above.

Comment: that’s bad, I could have tried for a while... thank you very much for your help! Now I need to find a way to have multiple backends without calling the graph api to verify each single time!